# Adobe Air Local Network P2P

Tags: networking, air, p2p

Is it possible to have Adobe Air application to communicate with each other between a group of PCs networked locally and not connected to the internet? The command send from PC A to PC B, C, D, E, F have to be very fast so that all PCs receive the command at the same time and running the process. Is it possible to do that with Adobe Air? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes sure connect PC over network you may use socket to connect. Server send data to connected client. Please check

> http://robertbak.com/wordpress/2011/10/example-basic-socket-server-in-air/

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the link. The example works, but only locally. Meaning, when it is listen and connect to 127.0.0.1, it works. But when I tried to get it connect to between 2 computers (192.168.1.34 and 192.168.1.23), it doesn't work. If I try to do that by running the server in debug mode, flex show the error message: "Error #2002: Operation attempted on invalid socket."

Comment: This error questionad in Adobe. Other devices not supported socket. Please check this http://forums.adobe.com/message/4372836

Comment: Thanks for reply. But all my connections are to PC running windows 7. It shouldn't be the device is not supported the socket, right? I have also tried to turn off firewall, but it is still the same.

Comment: Are you check the two computer connected? Are you ping the other computer?

Comment: Yes, both computers are connected. I have tried to ping, and gets the return.

Comment: I dont know the problem solution but you may try this example http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html